# What is the maximum sprint speed?

Tags: destiny-2

Mida multitool makes you sprint faster, minitool increases that factor too.

Are there more weapons with this effect? Are they cumulative? What is the maximum sprint speed you can have?

I know mobility is only for walking and jumping.

Comment: I don't know what the exact numbers are, but a friend of mine had gear that increased his speed to the max with a few perks that increased it even further. Lets just say that he was able to run faster than a sparrow

Comment: I believe it also affects slide distance.

Comment: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/73ioge/breakdown_of_mobility_and_sprint_speed/) are some researches (though I can't determine is it 1st or 2nd Destiny, confirm someone). TLDR; there is a cap 10% increase, multitool alone provides almost 9%, no need to use anything else.

Comment: Wondercricket, Sinatr, one of you might want to research more, because there is now a bounty on the question.

Comment: @Sinatr That is definitely Destiny 2. Since you found the source, I'll give you the honors of adding the answer for the bounty

Comment: @Wondercricket How you know is definitely 2 and not 1?

Comment: Can't actually reach the max sprint speed, because the more you play the slower you move.

Comment: @Malkev The reason I can tell is D2 is due to Mida-Mini tool. This weapon was not in D1. Plus the subreddit post defines it as Mobility, it was defined as Agility in D1

Comment: @Wondercricket oh, cool! Didn't played the 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the maximum sprint speed you can have?

According [to tests](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/73ioge/breakdown_of_mobility_and_sprint_speed/) made by some good guy on reddit, there is a cap of `10%` sprint speed increase.

`MIDA Multi-tool` gives `8.5%` bonus, adding `mini-tool` will adds `1.5%`.

> Are there more weapons with this effect?

Yes, any weapon with [lightweight perk](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Weapon_Perks) will increase sprint speed by `5%`.

There are also items (e.g. warlock's [Transversive Steps](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Transversive_Steps) exotic boots) and skills (e.g. hunter's [Keen Scout](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Keen_Scout) and [Focusing Breathing](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Focused_Breathing)) which are boosting sprint speed by same `5%`.

> Are they cumulative?

Yes, but due to cap it makes sense to use up to 2 items/skills with such bonus.

Comment: How are you sure this is Destiny 2 and not 1? The subreddit is for the 1.

Comment: @Malkev, for me it was enough to get confirmation from just one random guy... joking ;) I am taking a risk because the post is 1 month old (for Destiny 1 the same question would be years ago) and I've checked names of skills, items, etc... they match to Destiny 2 and my experience (I am playing it now).

Comment: marked as correct, then. You get the bounty in a couple of hours. ;)